# I need to write a post api that returns 201 as my http code. Java

Tags: java, spring

```
@PostMapping
public void registerCustomer(@RequestBody Customer customer){
    customerService.addCustomer(customer);

}
```

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar No matter which name you choose, most of the world's code comes from StackOverflow :)

Comment: @yoni First of all, that's nonsense, second of all, there's a difference between someone helping another dev and someone doing their job for them.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how your controller method should look like -

```java
  @PostMapping
  @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.CREATED)
  public void registerCustomer(@RequestBody Customer customer){
    customerService.addCustomer(customer);
  }
```

Ideally you should also send location header as well when you send a 201 response code. Something like this -

```java
  @PostMapping
  public ResponseEntity<Void> registerCustomer(@RequestBody Customer customer) {
    Integer customerId = customerService.addCustomer(customer);
    return ResponseEntity.created(URI.create("/customer/"+customerId)).build();
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that `customerService.addCustomer` returns the created Customer

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<Customer> registerCustomer(@RequestBody Customer customer){
    Customer createdCustomer = customerService.addCustomer(customer);
    return new ResponseEntity<Customer>(createdCustomer, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```